# Raphael's Odyssey

Tags: riddle

One night, Raphael decided to take an exuberant stroll around a very beautiful garden or in other words, embark on an formidable odyssey. The garden, comprising solely of fruitful facets of nature, was indeed very captivating to the eye. One might even infer that the garden is virtually priceless, that it requires no introduction. One glance at the garden is enough to instill in the witness an vivacious aesthesis that is perhaps impossible to explain. The boundaries of the garden were perfectly coated with electromagnetic ligaments made out of metal. Raphael, speaking earnestly, is a very intelligent man. But at that night, his hands were weightless. To get around the weightlessness, he brought with himself some support consisting of a place to rest the pedal on for the act of propelling spatially higher. As he entered the garden, he was petrified rather than astonished. Thirty minutes later,  his hands were surrounded with metallic loops.

What happened to Raphael?

Comment: Is the man inside or outside of the garden at the beginning?

Comment: He is ofcourse, outside the garden at the beginning.

Comment: This should be a simple logical puzzle to solve.

Comment: Is this one of those cryptic riddles where the story is just a frame to hide the actual content?

Comment: @xnor This is what we call a [Travis](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/5626/travis-kindred)-style riddle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Raphael was clearly a mental patient in an Asylum who thought he was outside a garden. (The garden filled with illusions of fruitful facets of nature). We can infer that the "garden" is priceless because of the large amount of drugs and sedatives stored in it - in fact, it may be some room in the area filled with drugs. His weightless hands can be described as "numb hands", possibly from sedatives he had been given earlier in the night. He tried to break into it to get more drugs (possibly morphine addiction?), climbing over an electric fence with a ladder or prop or stilt or something of the sort, and ended up being caught. Handcuffs around his hands are the metal loops.

Comment: Splendid! You solved it.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm not sure about the nature of the "garden," but it's clearly well-guarded and illegal to enter. Raphael attempted to break in, using a ladder to get over an electric fence, and was promptly arrested upon reaching the ground.
>
>  It's probably something less literal than that, though.

Answer (score 1):

The garden is clearly the Eden garden and the metallic loop is a ring. 
After breaking up with Adam, Eva decides to marry Raphael, the only man in there, so the metallic loop is actually a wedding ring! Poor Raphael!

Additional note: "hand-ring" pronounce is very similar to "entering"!